# Looking for documentation of OGR SetSpatialFilter

Tags: ogr, spatial-filter

I need documentation on how to apply a spatial filter (using OGR's SetSpatialFilter).

Setting the feature layer by which another layer should be filtered seems rather straightforward. But, how do you set the type of spatial filtering ('intersect', 'contain' etc.). And where do you find a list of optional types?

In the case at hand, I would like to filter out features from one layer (let's call it 'TilePolys')that are touched ('intersects with' (?)) by features from another layer (let's call it 'Buildings).

Comment: Intersects is actually the only filter that SetSpatialFilter can use. Documentation is in http://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#a0b4ab45cf97cbc470f0d60474d3e4169

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [link](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#SetSpatialFilter) to the documentation, with the following content:

> ````
> SetSpatialFilter(Layer self, int iGeomField, Geometry filter)
>
> void OGR_L_SetSpatialFilter(OGRLayerH hLayer, OGRGeometryH hGeom)
>
> Set a new spatial filter.
>
> This function set the geometry to be used as a spatial filter when
> fetching features via the OGR_L_GetNextFeature() function. Only
> features that geometrically intersect the filter geometry will be
> returned.
>
> Currently this test is may be inaccurately implemented, but it is
> guaranteed that all features whose envelope (as returned by
> OGR_G_GetEnvelope()) overlaps the envelope of the spatial filter will
> be returned. This can result in more shapes being returned that should
> strictly be the case.
>
> Starting with GDAL 2.3, features with null or empty geometries will
> never be considered as matching a spatial filter.
>
> This function makes an internal copy of the passed geometry. The
> passed geometry remains the responsibility of the caller, and may be
> safely destroyed.
>
> For the time being the passed filter geometry should be in the same
> SRS as the layer (as returned by OGR_L_GetSpatialRef()). In the future
> this may be generalized.
>
> This function is the same as the C++ method
> OGRLayer::SetSpatialFilter.
>
> Parameters:
> -----------
>
> hLayer:  handle to the layer on which to set the spatial filter.
>
> hGeom:  handle to the geometry to use as a filtering region. NULL may
> be passed indicating that the current spatial filter should be
> cleared, but no new one instituted.  ```
> ````

---

Using python would be as simple as follows:

```
from osgeo import ogr

ds = ogr.Open(shapefile)
lyr = ds.GetLayer()  # TilePolys

wkt = "POLYGON ((-103.81402655265633 50.253951270672125,-102.94583419409656 51.535568561879401,-100.34125711841725 51.328856095555651,-100.34125711841725 51.328856095555651,-93.437060743203844 50.460663736995883,-93.767800689321859 46.450441890315041,-94.635993047881612 41.613370178339181,-100.75468205106476 41.365315218750681,-106.12920617548238 42.564247523428456,-105.96383620242338 47.277291755610058,-103.81402655265633 50.253951270672125))"

geometry = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)   # Buildings

lyr.SetSpatialFilter(geometry)
```

In this case the geometry is made from a Wkt but you can use whatever geometry you like. Usually you would import the shapefile where your 'filtering' feature(s) is (are) and use it to set the spatial filter.

As the comment above says, intersection is the only filter that works with `SetSpatialFilter` and would work in your case.